# How to to use bevel and emboss properly for clean buttons in photoshop cs6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects, cs6, interface-design

I've heard of different methods in getting a nice highlight on the top of a button.  Can some of you explain a preferred fx for the example here? Along side the nice highlight on the top of the button, can you explain how each button is tastefully differentiated?

http://dribbble.com/shots/391714-Archivme-iPad-app-iOS?list=searches&tag=buttons

[image]

Comment: Semi-related questions that might help: [Create an “pressed in” look](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13963/create-an-pressed-in-look/13964#13964) and [Photoshop: how to create buttons that look “subtly pushed”?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/photoshop-how-to-create-buttons-that-look-subtly-pushed/13663#13663)

Comment: I should have clarified.  Not looking at the pressed look.  So ignore that.  But the buttons themselves.

Comment: it's just a gradient fill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Blue Button]

[Download the psd here click on the blue-button.psd text in top left corner](https://www.pixelapse.com/s/2ENM42YNZ37P4TV4)

Its all done with gradients, inner shadow for the highlight at the top and for the shadow round the edge i used a bevel. You can download the psd above ^. Its all a little off just were a picked random colors from the jpeg.